# Java date pattern for SQL date (ISO 9075)

Tags: java, sql, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse an SQL date string (ISO 9075) and that uses microseconds(!) instead of milliseconds, for example

```
2010-11-22 08:08:08.123456
```

However, SimpleDateFormat refuses to recognize a pattern like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS" and "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" does not work, either.

The code I am using looks something like this:

```
String dateString = "2010-11-22 08:08:08.123456";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS";

try
{
    format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    format.setLenient(false);
    position.setIndex(0);
    Date date1 = format.parse(dateString, position);
    System.out.println("Date 1: " + date1);
    Date date2 = format.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println("Date 2: " + date1);
}
catch (Exception e) // Should not happen
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Whichever of the 2 patterns (".SSS" or ".SSSSSS") I use, date1 is printer as `null`, whereas date2 causes a parsing exception (java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe chop the remaining fraction part out of the dateString before parse the date? I have the following

```
    String dateString = "2010-11-22 08:08:08.123456";
    String fraction = dateString.substring(dateString.length() - 3);
    String formatString = dateString.substring(0, dateString.length() - 3);
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);

    try
    {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        format.setLenient(false);
        position.setIndex(0);
        Date date1 = format.parse(formatString, position);          
        System.out.println("Date 1: " + date1);
        System.out.println("Date 1 fraction: " + fraction);
        Date date2 = format.parse(formatString);
        System.out.println("Date 2: " + date2);
        System.out.println("Date 2 fraction: " + fraction);
    }
    catch (Exception e) // Should not happen
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This allow the date to parse until millisecond precision while you still retain the fraction micro part.

Comment: Is the fractional/microsecond part guaranteed to be exactly 6 digits? E.g. will it be `:08.123450` or will it be truncated to `:08.12345` when ending in zero(s)? I'd probably look for the decimal and take 3 digits following it, rather than dropping length-3 depending on the answer.

Comment: @StephenP that is a good question and good suggestion. If i understand correctly to achieve better interoperability, a standard is created and in this discussion, it is iso 9075. If the example end with 0, it should always come with zero. (I have not check in that iso 9075 yet)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  Given that `Date` doesn't have microsecond resolution, *if* you know that all the SQL date strings have the full six digits after the seconds decimal point (`2010-11-22 08:08:08.000000` for example), why not just chop off the final three digits and use `SimpleDateFormat` on the remainder?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [DATE4J](http://www.date4j.net/) which specifically tries to deal with *database* dates, to nanosecond precision.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to call the DateFormat parse, because I think it will cut off the string. Try:

```
Date date1 = format.parse(dateString);
```

Plus, don't use "SSSSS". According to specs, only "SSS" is valid for dateformat.

Other than that, I agree with cutting it off or parsing in SQL.

Plus, you have setLenient to false, so it's strict. So the string, being longer is going to cause it to fail. Maybe that's why it returns null. Unsure, would have to test.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Insert/Update.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    Instant.parse( "2010-11-22 08:08:08.123456".replace( " " , "T" ) + "Z" ) 
) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
String output = ldt.toString().replace( "T" , " " ) ;  // Remove the standard ISO 8601 format’s use of `T` in the middle with the SQL-style SPACE.
```

## java.time

[Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29) brings the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), to supplant the notoriously troublesome old java.util.Date, .Calendar, and SimpleDateFormat classes. Those old legacy classes are limited to milliseconds resolution while your input string has microseconds. You cannot cram six decimal places into a data type limited to three.

The date-time values in *java.time* have [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution, more than enough for your microseconds. That means up to *nine* decimal places for a fractional second.

With JDBC 4.2 and later, use the `Instant` class directly.

Parse your input String. To comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format used by default in the java.time classes, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`. Your given example must be coming from a column type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` which means *not* a specific moment, *not* a point on the timeline.

```
String input = "2010-11-22 08:08:08.123456".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

And if this input was meant to be a moment in UTC, append a `Z`. Then you *do* have a moment, a specific point on the timeline. For use with a column type of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
String input = "2010-11-22 08:08:08.123456".replace( " " , "T" ) + "Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

Send to your database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

UPDATE: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Leaving this section intact as history.

## Joda-Time

As noted above, you should avoid using the java.util.Date, .Calendar, and SimpleDateFormat classes. As of Java 8 you have the choice of using java.time or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or both, as they each their strengths and weaknesses. Joda-Time also works in earlier versions of Java.

You can parse that string using Joda-Time.

Alternatively, if you have access to the java.sql.Timestamp that generated your string, you can simply pass the Timestamp object to the constructor of a DateTime. I suggest also passing a time zone as DateTime objects know their own assigned time zone.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( mySqlTimestamp, DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

or

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( mySqlTimestamp, DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );
```

Joda-Time has a resolution of *[milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond)*. So either way you generate the DateTime (parsing or passing), you will loose the finer fraction of the second (ignored/truncated, not rounded).

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the SQL date which is an input to the java code, you could try and retrieve the date from SQL in a format which will work ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").